# Why Cookies will not be stored if setting Timeout = 30 days in GWT?

Tags: gwt

This is very weird. Ok, the below code works fine

```
public void setCookie(String cookiesName, String cookiesValue){
    final int COOKIE_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;//1 days
    Date expires = new Date((new Date()).getTime() + COOKIE_TIMEOUT);
    Cookies.setCookie(cookiesName, cookiesValue, expires);
}
//then
setCookie("currentLang","de");
Collection<String> cookies = Cookies.getCookieNames();
for(String cookie : cookies){
        if("currentLang".equals(cookie)){
              System.out.println("got currentlang");
        }
}
```

If i run the above code then I can see output: "**got currentlang**"
However, if I set timeout=30 days `final int COOKIE_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;//30 days`, then nothing got printed out, so "currentLang" has not even been stored if we set 30 days?

Why is that? does Gwt prevent that to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using integer arithmetic for a sum that overflows beyond the maximum positive value for an integer. So 1000*60*60*24*30 is negative.

You could try 1000L*60*60*24*30

Comment: u means final long COOKIE_TIMEOUT = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;//30 days? ti works but why we have to put L after 1000, if i don't put L after 1000 then it won't work

Comment: 1000L is interpreted as a long with value 1000, so the multiplication will all be done as a long instead of integer.